# Bind Realm's Results<Object> to NSArrayController content array

Tags: swift, macos, realm, nsarraycontroller

I am working on a small macOS project and I would like to implement something similar with this: [Realm + NSTableView + NSArrayController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41970072/realm-nstableview-nsarraycontroller). Is it possible to use Realm's`Results<Object>`
 query as NSArrayController's content array and take advantage of Realm's notifications or do I have to map the Realm query results to a swift array of `Object` s and feed the NSArrayController?